# How to rewrite this type of url via htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got this Rewrite Rule.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+))/? /index.php?show=news&id=$1
```

Now I need to add some GET data (partner) to the end of url. F.e. /news/1/?partner=some_partner

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+))/(.*)*? /index.php$2&show=news&id=$1
```

Because I'm gathering partner data

```
if (isset($_GET['partner'])) addPartnerStat($_GET['partner']);
```

And I need exactly this url's view /news/1/?partner=some_partner, not /news/1/partner/some_partner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the QSA Flag?

```
  RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+))/? /index.php?show=news&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

More Informations about the Flags you get here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be work:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+))/partner/(.*)$ /index.php$2&show=news&id=$1&partner=$2
```

Comment: Yeah I now. But I need exactly this url's view /news/1/?partner=some_partner